# constructor DepartmentChooser in class DepartmentChooser can not be applied to given types

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, bluej

I have been asked to create a programme for my university, the programme was going well until I got 2 errors, I have been trying to fix them for a while now, I read most of the posts in here but unfortunately they did not help me.
now the first error is "constructor DepartmentChooser in class DepartmentChooser can not be applied to given types"
and the second is "Registration is not an abstract and dose not override abstract method actionPerformed"

the programme contains few classes, but i've attach some of them.

hope you can help me as the deadline is soon.
thanks

#### departmentChooser

```
//import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.event.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class DepartmentChooser here.
 * 
 * @author () 
 * @version (19/07/2014)
 */
public class DepartmentChooser extends JPanel implements ListSelectionListener
{
   private static ChooserListener callback;
   private JList Settings;
   private Department[] departments;
   private JFrame frame;
   private String DepartmentCode;
   private String[] adding;
   
   
   public DepartmentChooser (ChooserListener callback, School s)
   {
       super ();
       this.callback = callback;
       
       Collection <Department> x = s.getDepartments ();
       departments = new Department [x.size()];
       String [] adding = new String [x.size()];
       int i = 0;
       
       for (Iterator itr = x.iterator (); itr.hasNext();)
       {
           departments [i] = (Department) itr.next ();
           adding [i] = departments [i].getName();  
           i++;
        }
        
        Settings = new JList (adding);
        Settings.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        //Settings.SetColor(Color.gray);
        Settings.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //Settings.addMouseListener(mouseclicks);
        Settings.addListSelectionListener(this);
        Settings.setVisibleRowCount(6);
        add (new JScrollPane (Settings));
    }
    
    public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            Department lister = departments [Settings.getSelectedIndex()];
            if (lister == null)
            {
                System.out.println ("Empty");
            }
            else
            {
                callback.tell(lister);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public ChooserListener getCallBack ()
    {
        return this.callback;
    }
    
    public Department [] getDepartments()
    {
        return this.departments;
    }
    
    public void repeat()
    {
        int i = Settings.getSelectedIndex();
        if (i < 0)
        {
            callback.tell(null);
        }
        else
        {
            callback.tell (departments[i]);
        }
    }
    
    public void passThrough (Object o)
    {
        if (o instanceof Department)
        {
            Department list = (Department) o;
            System.out.println(list.getCode());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is to test it

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class DepartmentTester here.
 * 
 * @author () 
 * @version (20/07/2014)
 */
public class DepartmentTester implements ChooserListener 
{
    public DepartmentTester()
    {
        Loader.load();
        School sch = School.get("SCIM");
        DepartmentChooser DepartmentCho = new DepartmentChooser(sch,null);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Department Chooser");
        frame.add (DepartmentCho);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
    
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        new DepartmentTester();
    }
    
    public void tell (Object o)
    {
        System.out.println(((School)o).getName() + "\n");
    }
    
}
```

and last this is where I'm getting the error

> "Registration is not an abstract and dose not override abstract method actionPerformed"

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.event.*;

/**
 * Write a description of class DepartmentChooser here.
 * 
 * @author () 
 * @version (19/07/2014)
 */
public class DepartmentChooser extends JPanel implements ListSelectionListener
{
   private static ChooserListener callback;
   private JList Settings;
   private Department[] departments;
   private JFrame frame;
   private String DepartmentCode;
   private String[] adding;
   
   
   public DepartmentChooser (ChooserListener callback, School s)
   {
       super ();
       this.callback = callback;
       
       Collection <Department> x = s.getDepartments ();
       departments = new Department [x.size()];
       String [] adding = new String [x.size()];
       int i = 0;
       
       for (Iterator itr = x.iterator (); itr.hasNext();)
       {
           departments [i] = (Department) itr.next ();
           adding [i] = departments [i].getName();  
           i++;
        }
        
        Settings = new JList (adding);
        Settings.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        //Settings.SetColor(Color.gray);
        Settings.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        //Settings.addMouseListener(mouseclicks);
        Settings.addListSelectionListener(this);
        Settings.setVisibleRowCount(6);
        add (new JScrollPane (Settings));
    }
    
    public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            Department lister = departments [Settings.getSelectedIndex()];
            if (lister == null)
            {
                System.out.println ("Empty");
            }
            else
            {
                callback.tell(lister);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public ChooserListener getCallBack ()
    {
        return this.callback;
    }
    
    public Department [] getDepartments()
    {
        return this.departments;
    }
    
    public void repeat()
    {
        int i = Settings.getSelectedIndex();
        if (i < 0)
        {
            callback.tell(null);
        }
        else
        {
            callback.tell (departments[i]);
        }
    }
    
    public void passThrough (Object o)
    {
        if (o instanceof Department)
        {
            Department list = (Department) o;
            System.out.println(list.getCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The DepartmentChooser class takes ChooserListener and School as an argument and you  are passing 
DepartmentChooser DepartmentCho = new DepartmentChooser(sch,null);
School as your first argument, which is type mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to read the error message:

> constructor DepartmentChooser in class DepartmentChooser can not be applied to given types

That means you're not passing the right types to the DepartmentChooser constructor. And indeed, the constructor is defined as

```
public DepartmentChooser (ChooserListener callback, School s)
```

It thus takes a ChooserListener as first argument, and a School as second argument. And you're calling it using

```
School sch = School.get("SCIM");
DepartmentChooser DepartmentCho = new DepartmentChooser(sch,null);
```

So you pass a School as first argument instead of a ChooserListener, and null as second argument.

You didn't post the code of Registration, but the message is also self-explanatory:

> Registration is not an abstract and dose not override abstract method actionPerformed

So you probably defined the Registration class as

```
public class Registration implements ActionListener {
    ...
}
```

Since you declare that the class implements [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), it must implement the methods defined in the ActionListener interface. It must thus have the following method:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ...
}
```

Or maybe it shouldn't implement ActionListener.

Comment: I can not thank you enough, I have managed to solve the first problem.

Comment: however I tired to Override my registration but still no joy, if you can give me more advice about it that would be amazing, I checked the code for registration is posted now.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The DepartmentChooser class takes ChooserListener and School as an argument and you are passing

```
     DepartmentChooser DepartmentCho = new DepartmentChooser(sch,null);
```

School as your first argument, which is type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

for the first error:

you are instantiating object without passing a parameter but in your constructor you have two parameter so it is not compatible

for the second error:

you are using an interface, you should create the body for each of the method on the interface you are implementing